# editor.js:69 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a blog site this is the page where I make and publish the blog however every time I hit the publish button this error pops up:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (editor.js:69:20)
```

I have the proper config for firebase and I have set up firestore with the collection blogs so I don't understand why it's not working.

**editor.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>blog editor</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/editor.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="banner-upload" hidden>
        <label for="banner-upload" class="banner-upload-btn"><img src="img/upload.png" alt="upload banner"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="blog">
        <textarea type="text" class="title" placeholder="Blog title..."></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="article" placeholder="Start writing here..."></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-options">
        <button class="btn dark publish-btn">publish</button>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image-upload" hidden>
        <label for="image-upload" class="btn grey upload-btn">Upload Image</label>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="js/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/editor.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**editor.js**

```
const blogTitleField = document.querySelector('.title');
const articleFeild = document.querySelector('.article');

// banner
const bannerImage = document.querySelector('#banner-upload');
const banner = document.querySelector(".banner");
let bannerPath;

const publishBtn = document.querySelector('.publish-btn');
const uploadInput = document.querySelector('#image-upload');

bannerImage.addEventListener('change', () => {
    uploadImage(bannerImage, "banner");
})

uploadInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    uploadImage(uploadInput, "image");
})

const uploadImage = (uploadFile, uploadType) => {
    const [file] = uploadFile.files;
    if(file && file.type.includes("image")){
        const formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('image', file);

        fetch('/upload', {
            method: 'post',
            body: formdata
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(uploadType == "image"){
                addImage(data, file.name);
            } else{
                bannerPath = `${location.origin}/${data}`;
                banner.style.backgroundImage = `url("${bannerPath}")`;
            }
        })
    } else{
        alert("upload Image only");
    }
}

const addImage = (imagepath, alt) => {
    let curPos = articleFeild.selectionStart;
    let textToInsert = `\r![${alt}](${imagepath})\r`;
    articleFeild.value = articleFeild.value.slice(0, curPos) + textToInsert + articleFeild.value.slice(curPos);
}




let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

publishBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(articleFeild.value.length && blogTitleField.value.length){
        // generating id
        let letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        let blogTitle = blogTitleField.value.split(" ").join("-");
        let id = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            id += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
        }

        // setting up docName
        let docName = `${blogTitle}-${id}`;
        let date = new Date(); // for published at info

        //access firstore with db variable;
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection("blogs").doc(docName).set({
            title: blogTitleField.value,
            article: articleFeild.value,
            bannerImage: bannerPath,
            publishedAt: `${date.getDate()} ${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`
        })
        .then(() => {
            location.href = `/${docName}`;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        })
    }
})
```

**firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getFirestore} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-firestore.js";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "its in my project file just not here",
  authDomain: "the-butler-353f4.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "the-butler-353f4",
  storageBucket: "the-butler-353f4.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "804499070225",
  appId: "1:804499070225:web:28bf3f44bf8bc3a38100b0"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();

export { app, db };
```

I'm making an editor page, the thing giving me trouble is the publish button which will publish the blog on the site and have the blog stored in firebase's firestore database.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<script type="module" src="js/firebase-config.js"></script>` ? Since `firebase-config.js` is what you called it

Comment: sry bout that i accidentally called it firebase config while writing the post but it actually just called firebase.js. i appreciate the comment and your suggestion :-)

Comment: Also ... I noticed that your Firebase API key is showing. It's important to keep your API key private and secure to prevent unauthorized access to your Firebase project.

Comment: You need to use v9 Firebase syntax,  `const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection("blogs").doc(docName).set({...` is old v8 Firebase syntax . Check the  [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9)

Comment: Please be mindful of where you place your backticks. Putting random backticks all over your document and not ensuring you properly fence your codeblocks makes your post not render properly. I've fixed it for you. For more help please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: @MihailNicoara whats new syntax then? i figured the code was dated but i wasnt sure what to look up im new to coding you see

Answer (score 0):

Firebase v9 uses ES modules for importing Firebase modules, so you need to use module scripts to work with Firebase v9. This means that you would need to refactor your code to use module scripts. However, you can still use Firebase v8 with non-module scripts. To use v8 Firebase you should change your Firebase initialization to something like this :

```
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
        <script>
            const firebaseConfig = {
             // your firebase config 
            };
           firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
           const db = firebase.firestore();
           
          </script>
```

Also delete the `type=module` from the `firebase.js` script tag like:
`<script src="js/firebase.js"></script>`
This should make your code work.
Also make sure you remove this line from the `editor.js` :

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Note that Firebase v8 is not officially deprecated yet, but it is recommended to migrate to v9 as soon as possible since it is the latest version and has some new features and improvements. It is also worth noting that Firebase v8 will eventually be deprecated in the future.